# How to write search query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

my event table with starteventdate and endevent date.

```
         Id  EventName starteventdate endevent
        ---------------------------------------
         1    a        7/6/2014       8/6/2014
         2    b        9/6/2014       10/6/2014
         3    c        10/6/2014      15/6/2014
```

my search screen have fromdate and todate. so i want to search events between two dates those events are active.

> i'm searching events between 7/6/2014- 10/6/2014  result -->1,2,3.
>
> if i'm searching events between 10/6/2014-12/6/2014  result -->2,3.
>
> if i'm searching events between 8/6/2013-20/6/2014 result-->1,2,3

i tried this query.but i'm able to seach b/w only one date like

```
SELECT e.EventsID,e.EventDesc AS 'Event Description' 
FROM dEvents e  
WHERE convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),StartEvent,101),101) 
   BETWEEN 
       convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),@FromDate,101),101) 
   AND
       convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),@ToDate,101),101).
```

so i want only active events which are b/w search dates.please sort this out.

Comment: Are `starteventdate`/`end event`/`@FromDate`/`@ToDate` [date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) types? If not, why not, and can you fix that first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this assuming you have `DATETIME` types to work with, instead of strings. You should be able to put the `CONVERT`s back in though, if necessary.

```
SELECT e.EventsID, e.EventDesc AS 'Event Description' 
  FROM dEvents e 
 WHERE EndEvent >= @FromDate
   AND StartEvent <= @ToDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Observation, you are storing dd/mm/yyyy so use 103 for conversion

**Sample Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dEvents')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dEvents
END

CREATE TABLE dEvents (Id INT,EventName VARCHAR(10),StartEvent VARCHAR(20),endevent VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO dEvents VALUES
('1','a','7/6/2014','8/6/2014'),
('2','b','9/6/2014','10/6/2014'),
('3','c','10/6/2014','15/6/2014')
```

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @FromDate VARCHAR(20) = '7/6/2014'
DECLARE @ToDate VARCHAR(20) = '10/6/2014'

SELECT e.ID,e.EventName AS 'Event Description' 
FROM dEvents e  
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,StartEvent,103) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,@FromDate,103) AND CONVERT(DATE,@ToDate,103)
OR CONVERT(DATE,endevent,103) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,@FromDate,103) AND CONVERT(DATE,@ToDate,103)
```

**Cleanup:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dEvents')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dEvents
END
```

Comment: Note that this query will miss on events which start before the parameters and end after them. I would suggest using Mark's method regarding the date comparisons.

Comment: @Kahn why would you think the query will miss events. Please can you elaborate so I can correct any logic flaws.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I tried to say it there. :) What I mean is that when an event starts BEFORE FromDate, and ends AFTER ToDate, then neither value will be found BETWEEN FromDate and ToDate. Mark got that right in his answer, when he instead compared: StartEvent <= ToDate AND EndEvent >= FromDate.

Comment: To offer an example, see this fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19307/1/0  I used your response and added one new commented row to the dEvents table. That won't show up, even though it should. :)

Comment: Ok,I think I understand your concern, Between also includes the value. so Value between a and b is same as Value >= a and <= b. Also as I am converting to Date and not datetime, all dates from midnight to midnight is considered(complete day)

Comment: See the fiddle example above, please, that will illustrate the issue.

Comment: So let me bread it down so to see if we are talking on the same page. What I designed is get all people who have registered for a class and completed between FromDAte and ToDate. Obviously there will be people whos Start date is older and end day is newer but per criteria they should not be considered. Makes sense? Please try the parameters provided by @nixen09 and see if it works please.

Comment: To be fair, there is no information up there about registering for or completing classes. The OP simply asks for events which are active during a date range, which to my mind clearly implies that events which start before and end after the range, should be included. But your query does exactly what you wanted it to do, so that's fine. It's up to the OP then to decide what he needs. This is a classic question of interpretation after all. :)

Comment: True that @Kahn. The same thing when you apply to insurance, your logic would be spot on and the query would need to be modified :).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question.

So you have two parameters: @FromDate, and @ToDate. And you want to return all rows from **dEvents** table, where an event is active during the time between those two parameter dates?

You seem to be doing a lot of conversions there though, aren't you dealing with date or datetime datatypes?

Try this then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EventsID,e.EventDesc AS 'Event Description' 
from dEvents e  
WHERE @FromDate BETWEEN starteventdate AND endevent 
OR @ToDate BETWEEN starteventdate AND endevent
OR (@FromDate < starteventdate AND @ToDate > endevent)
```

Comment: The ORs will be less efficient than a query using ANDs.

Comment: Only marginally since this isn't used for a complex calculation or JOIN logic. But you're right, Mark's logic was much better here. My brain never seems to get these range comparison formulas. :(